# How to change sql date format of existing records in table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a datetime column which is storing records as

Mar 10 2020 12:00AM

but want to change all to format like 03/10/20

there are thousand of records

I tried, `COnvert(date,convert(varchar, PostingDate, 101),101)`

Comment: If the data type really is `datetime` there is no format stored. The format you see is the format the client is representing the data. You need to change the client settings if you want another default format. And if the datatype is `varchar` you should change it to `datetime`.

Comment: The SQL Server datetime type is a binary structure without a display format. It's the client application that formats the value for display purposes. To convert the value to a formatted string in T-SQL, use style 1: `CONVERT(char(8), PostingDate, 1)`. It would be better to do that in tthe application code, though.

Comment: Of all the formats, I really suggest against one with 2 digit years; what date would `01/02/03` be? 01 February 2003? 02 January 1903? 03 February 2001? Perhaps even 02 March 1901?

Comment: 20 years after Y2K and no one should be storing 2 digit years. **NO ONE **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the column is really a string, not a `datetime`.

SQL Server has a pretty flexible conversion to date.  First check to be sure that all the dates convert:

```
select col
from t
where try_convert(date, col) is null and col is not null;
```

If you are satisfied with the conversion, you can do:

```
update t
    set col = try_convert(date, col);

alter table t alter col date;
```